# Image doesn't load AngularJS WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, web, webstorm

I have an angularjs app that i need to load a local image so did this inside `view1.html`

```
<div class="ffg"
     style="border:2px solid;padding:10px;">
     <!-- border and padding only to show perspective -->
    <img class="backimg" src={{img_source}}/>
</div>
```

abd this inside `view1.js`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {
  $scope.img_source = 'app/views/images/dd.jpg';
}]);
```

And here is the image

[image]

**But the image doesn't show ?????**

Comment: Inspect the element with the Developer Console. Is the src attribute set correctly? Is there an error message?

Comment: It's recommended to use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to avoid having the browser try to fetch the literal string "{{img_source}}" as url before Angular has replaced the expression with the actual url.